# Comparing two LongWritable in if statement

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, key-value

how to compare two LongWritable in If statement ??? like,

```
if(compareTo(key1,new LongWritable(1))
 { 

    //do something;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LongWritable implements Comparable so use the compareTo method:

```
if (lw1.compareTo(lw2) == 0) {
  // lw1 has same value as lw2
}
```